# User is not authorized after user refreshes the website

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm making a website and i used passport-discord for authentication but when user is authenticated and refreshes the website the user is no more authenticated and i don't know the issue

```
const DiscordStrategy = require("passport-discord").Strategy;
const passport = require("passport");
const fs = require("fs");
let users = require("../users.json");
let profiles = require("../profiles.json");

require("dotenv").config();

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new DiscordStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.CLIENT_REDIRECT,
    scope: ['identify', 'guilds']
}, 
(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    profiles[profile.id] = {
        username: profile.username,
        avatarURL: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/" + profile.id + "/" + profile.avatar,
        banner: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/banners/" + profile.id + "/" + profile.banner,
        guilds: profile.guilds,
        id: profile.id
    }   

    fs.writeFile("./profiles.json", JSON.stringify(profiles, null, 4), err => {
        if(err) throw err;
    })

    let finduser = profiles[profile.id];
    console.log(finduser);
    done(null, finduser);
}));
```

server.js file:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secrettexthere',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 60000 * 60 * 24
    }
}))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get("/auth", passport.authenticate('discord'));
```

(im using json for now)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know passport-discord, but maybe I can help.
According your app behaviour it could be the case that you lose your accessToken on refresh. Maybe passport-discord is meant to do that, but implementing it manually you would have to save your accessToken in localStorage of the browser and reload it from there, when checking authorization.

Comment: I used MongoDB now and its fixed, my guess is forgot to add something thanks for replying btw!